# How to write one word in two different colors?

Tags: spacing, color

I have one word and would like to write it in two different colors. Usually, there will be a space between the two `\textcolo` sections

`\textcolor{sectcol}{la}\textcolor{white}{tex}`

I can "remove" the space with a negative `\hspace`.

`\textcolor{sectcol}{la}\hspace{-1mm}\textcolor{white}{tex}`

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: textcolor does not add space (but may prevent font specified kerns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

color inserts so-called `whatits`, and this will prevent kerning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
VA

\textcolor{red}{V}\textcolor{blue}{A}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is not much you can do about it (apart inserting negative space). The only way to really avoid it, is to use the lualatex engine and the luacolor package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacolor}

\begin{document}
VA

\textcolor{red}{V}\textcolor{blue}{A}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your example is not good, because there is no kerning between “a” and “t” in the standard fonts.

If you're stuck with `pdflatex` and can't use LuaTeX, you can manually compute the needed kerning.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\twocolors}{mmmm}
 {% #1 = color for the first part
  % #2 = first part
  % #3 = color for the second part
  % #4 = second part
  \egreg_twocolors:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\box_new:N \l__egreg_twocolors_kern_box
\box_new:N \l__egreg_twocolors_nokern_box

\cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_twocolors:nnnn
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__egreg_twocolors_kern_box
   {
    \tl_item:nn { #2 } { -1 }
    \tl_item:nn { #4 } { 1 } % could just be \tl_head:n
   }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__egreg_twocolors_nokern_box
   {
    \hbox:n { \tl_item:nn { #2 } { -1 } }
    \hbox:n { \tl_item:nn { #4 } { 1 } } % could just be \tl_head:n
   }
  \textcolor{#1}{#2}
  \skip_horizontal:n
   {
    \box_wd:N \l__egreg_twocolors_kern_box - \box_wd:N \l__egreg_twocolors_nokern_box
   }
  \textcolor{#3}{#4}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\twocolors{green!50!blue}{two}{red!30}{color}

twocolor

\makebox[0pt][l]{twocolor}\twocolors{green!50!blue}{two}{red!30}{color}
\makebox[0pt][l]{\twocolors{green!50!blue}{two}{red!30}{color}}twocolor

\twocolors{green!50!blue}{la}{red!30}{tex}

latex

\makebox[0pt][l]{latex}\twocolors{green!50!blue}{la}{red!30}{tex}
\makebox[0pt][l]{\twocolors{green!50!blue}{la}{red!30}{tex}}latex

\twocolors{green!50!blue}{V}{red!30}{A}

VA

\makebox[0pt][l]{VA}\twocolors{green!50!blue}{V}{red!30}{A}
\makebox[0pt][l]{\twocolors{green!50!blue}{V}{red!30}{A}}VA

\end{document}
```

Each example has the check that colors don't leak. However, at small resolutions, the rasterer might show artifacts. The image below has been taken at quite high resolution.

Limitation: if the last item in the first part or the first item in the second part is an accented letter, brace it (or them).

[image]

Comment: Very nice, but in my humble opinion, it would be more convenient if the colors were assigned globally or temporarily and then the macro that colors would have only one option: the number of characters of the word to be colored with the first color